# Oracle PL/SQL send email notification to user on data change

Tags: oracle, email, notifications

I have bulk data upload process in place through which am loading data into table called **TICKETS**. Below is the table structure with dummy data:

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| TicketID |     Email     | Payment_Hold |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
|        1 | smith@abc.com | YES          |
|        2 | john@abc.com  | NO           |
|        3 | mary@abc.com  | YES          |
|        4 | jane@abc.com  | YES          |
|        5 | king@abc.com  | NO           |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

After the upload process, data in few rows gets changed, either new rows are inserted or existing rows are updated. Below is snapshot of data after upload:

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| TicketID |     Email     | Payment_Hold |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
|        1 | blake@abc.com | YES          |
|        2 | john@abc.com  | YES          |
|        4 | jane@abc.com  | NO           |
|        5 | scott@abc.com | NO           |
|        6 | jim@abc.com   | YES          |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

With that being said, am trying to send notifications to person working on ticket whenever there is change in data in two columns ie.,

1. For a particular TicketID, if person gets changed and if the ticket has payment hold then send notification to new person working on ticket and
2. If payment hold on TicketID gets changed then send notification to the person working on ticket.

Best possible way I thought of achieving this is by creating value based auditing table and trigger (after insert or update) on the **TICKETS** table to capture changes. Below is the **TICKETS_AUDIT_TABLE**

```
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| ID  | TicketID |   Old Email   |   New Email   | Old_Payment_Hold | New_Payment_Hold |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| 100 |        1 | smith@abc.com | blake@abc.com | YES              | YES              |
| 200 |        2 | john@abc.com  | john@abc.com  | NO               | YES              |
| 300 |        4 | jane@abc.com  | jane@abc.com  | YES              | NO               |
| 400 |        5 | king@abc.com  | scott@abc.com | NO               | NO               |
| 500 |        6 | NULL          | jim@abc.com   | NULL             | YES              |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
```

And for the email, am using below pl/sql code:

```
DECLARE 
    vemailbody CLOB := NULL; 
    CURSOR c1 IS 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   tickets_audit_table 
      ORDER  BY id; 
BEGIN 
    wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id; 

    vemailbody := vemailbody 
                  || '<table><tr><th>Ticket Update</th></tr><tr> 
              <th><b>Ticket ID</b></th> 
              <th>Old Email</th> 
              <th>New Email</th> 
              <th>Old Payment Hold Flag</th> 
              <th>New Payment Hold Flag</th> </tr>'; 

    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP 

        vemailbody := vemailbody || '<tr> <td>' || rec.ticketid 
                             ||'</td> <td>' || rec.old_email 
                             ||'</td> <td>' || rec.new_email 
                             ||'</td> <td>' || rec.old_payment_hold 
                             ||'</td> <td>' || rec.new_payment_hold 
                             ||'</td> </tr>'|| utl_tcp.crlf; 
    END LOOP; 

    vemailbody := vemailbody || '</table>' || utl_tcp.crlf; 
    vemailbody := vemailbody || '<br>' || utl_tcp.crlf; 
    vemailbody := vemailbody || '</td>'|| utl_tcp.crlf; 
    vemailbody := vemailbody || '</tr>'|| utl_tcp.crlf; 
    vemailbody := vemailbody || '</table>'|| utl_tcp.crlf; 

    dbms_output.Put_line(vemailbody); 

    apex_mail.Send(p_to => 'richa@abc.com', 
                   p_from => 'Test Mail <test@abc.com>',
               p_subj => 'Ticket update',
           p_body => vemailbody, 
           p_body_html => vemailbody); 

    apex_mail.push_queue; 
END;
```

The issue here is, same email is triggered multiple times for the users who has previously received an email. Am not sure how to send email notification based on below conditions:
For Example: Considering Ticket ID = 1

- If (Old_Email is not equal to New_Email) AND (Old_Payment_Hold not equal to New_Payment_Hold) then send email only to New_Email
- If email is already sent for the ticket ID = 1 where (New_Email = Old_Email) and (Old_Payment_Hold = New_Payment_Hold) then do not resend email.

I really appreciate any help provided regarding this.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: How about having your email procedure insert/update/checks a new table that tracks whether user has been notified yet?

Comment: @MarkStewart thanks for the suggestion. I never thought about it. I can add a column in **TICKETS_AUDIT_TABLE** to capture notification sent. But in my pl/sql code how I can insert/update the value (yes or no) after sending an email. Also how can I know which row to update?

Comment: can I put apex_mail.send within IF conditions?

Comment: Sure: Imagine some CR/LF  `\n` in the following:

`if some_condition then \n    apex_mail(...):  \n end if;`